# Spring - DateFormat is not formatting dates properly for China

Tags: java, spring, date-format, date-formatting

I have a class that is preparing dates from `db format` **like 2015/02/13 into 13 February 2015**. Unfortunately this function works for English, French, but do not work for Chinese.

Here is what I got:

```
public class DateFormatTag extends TagSupport {
    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
       out.println(dateFormat(getInput()));
    }

    public String dateFormat(String input) throws ParseException {
        Locale locale = new Locale("cn", "zh");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", locale);
        Date date =  df.parse(input);
        SimpleDateFormat returnFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy", locale);
        return returnFormat.format(date);
    }
```

I hardcoded Chinese locale on purpose in order to test. Input is provided in format of: 2015/02/15 (yyyy/mm/dd).

I cannot find any better solution to solve this issue. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

The solution may be provided in Joda Time or in Java embedded classes.

Comment: I think u should use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will certainly look into it, but we would prefer to stay with embedded Java internationalization.

Comment: In the production application, the date should by displayed regarding selected country and language by the user. The locale is being created in the first line of dateFormat method.

Comment: Can you please provide an example in joda time?

Comment: @TheKolaNN just want to make sure, what is your expected output from that code?

Comment: Something like this (for China): 16 十一月 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your input format, you don't have to construct `SimpleDateFormat` with locale.
For the output, you **should have** read [the doc for Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date =  df.parse(input);
SimpleDateFormat returnFormat 
    = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy", Locale.CHINA); 
// or Locale.CHINESE, Locale.PRC, all work on my machine
return returnFormat.format(date);
```